# Taking the nusances out of AutoCloseable

Tags: java, java-7

Up front: I'm a C# guy doing Java right now. Some of these frustrations come from my lack of knowledge of Java.

First, is there a way to have a "safe" `AutoCloseable` implementation that does not require the `Exception` to be checked? If I'm implmementing my own class that won't throw from its `close` method, I don't see why I have to check it.

Second, is there a way to simplify the expression in the `try` statement where I don't care what's returned? For instance in C# I can do this:

```
using (new Disposable()) 
{
    // yay!
}
```

and Java seems to force me to assign it to a temporary variable:

```
try (AutoCloseable iDontCare = getAutoCloseable()) {
    // dont you dare use iDontCare
}
```

I wish I could simplify the Java to

```
try (getAutoCloseable()) {
    // yay!
}
```

Comment: @lucasvw i'm just wanting to simplify my code. internally its maintaining state. in C# we use this pattern to trace the scope of a block of code. when its done, it "pops" automatically whether or not the inner code threw or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what good the simplified java would do. If you don't assign it to a variable, you can't use it in the try block, thus there is no reason to close it if an exception is thrown in the try block.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a `try { } catch { }` block without any object?

Comment: @lucasvw trying to simplify the code here that adds a lot of ceremony.

Comment: Why would you open something and then not use it anywhere? By the way, there's a `Closeable` interface too, which still throws an `IOException`, but it's at least slightly less nasty than the vanilla `Exception`.

Comment: @biziclop its something that maintains state internally. its not something thats meant to be on operated

Comment: No. And no. If these things bother you, consider using Scala which eliminates checked exceptions and fixes all the other language flaws and omissions of Java.

Comment: I still don't get it. How does the code in the block change the state of your `AutoCloseable` object if it has no reference to it? This looks very much like an X-Y problem to me.

Comment: @biziclop the construction of the object that is the `Autoclosable` does something to keep, then lets it go on `close`.

Answer (score 3):

C# isn't quite Java; this is one of those gotchas you'll have to deal with going forward.

> First, is there a way to have a "safe" `AutoCloseable` implementation that does not require the `Exception` to be checked? If I'm implmementing my own class that won't throw from its `close` method, I don't see why I have to check it.

You *have* to because [it's mandated by the interface.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)  Not just that, but it throws a checked exception, which *does* have to be handled at some level.

If you know for a fact that your code will *never* throw any kind of exception, you could still place the throwing of the exception in some kind of guaranteed-not-to-be-executed-block inside of your implemented `close` method.  Or, implement your own interface which extends `AutoCloseable` and overrides `close` to *not* throw an exception.

Comment: i know its mandated by the interface, but i want to signal that my code is safe.

Comment: You're not going to get around the mandates by the interface.  You could simply *not* throw the exception or throw it in a case you know to be impossible to occur.  Regardless of how safe your code is, because you are implementing an interface, you are **strictly** beholden to that contract.

Comment: Just extend AutoCloseable and override the close() method without any thrown checked exception.

Answer (score 3):

Your first question:

Yes. You can implement AutoCloseable.close without the throws Exception part if your implementation doesn't throw checked exceptions.

Your second question:

No. The try with resources statement requires that variable. You can rename it to something like ignored or unused to make that clear.

```
final class Test implements AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Closing");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Test ignored = new Test()) {
            System.out.println("Not using ignored");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Makoto's answer does a nice job of addressing the first part of your question, so I'll attempt to address the second.

I think what you want is a try (without resources). For example:

```
try {
    //yay!
} finally {
   // always executed
}
```

The `finally` block will execute regardless of whether an exception is thrown or not.

**Edit:**
If you don't need anything to execute, you could just declare a new block

```
{
    //yay!
}
```

Comment: yea i know about that but thats a lot more ceremony than the `try` by itself.

Comment: Updated my answer. This might just be something you have to live with in Java, though I admit I'm still a little murky on what you're trying to accomplish